# What is the approximate value of treasure seized by privateers from 1567 to 1720?

Tags: united-kingdom, spain, piracy

What is the approximate value for the treasure seized by Spanish privateers from English ships between 1567 and 1720?

For example, *"Attacks by the Anglo-Dutch axis over the period 1567 to 1720 seized approximately X tons of gold."*

References :
http://pirateattack.co.uk/history/historyofpiracy
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privateer

Comment: So you want the results of **every ship action** from 1603 to 1720 from England and any ally they might have had, and the booty as well.  Good Luck with that.

Comment: Its difficult question,even professional historian have difficulty with it,because of little records sometimes,and alot of data other time

Comment: I have tried to edit this question and to respect OP's intent, but I'm not convinced that I haven't mangled the question horribly.